# How to apply indices I got from one row to other rows in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indices

Let say if I have this data

```
my_data = [ 10 20 30 40; 0.1 0.7 0.4 0.3; 6 1 2 3; 2 5 4 2];
my_index = logical(my_data(4,:)==2);
```

What is the simplest way to use 'my_index' to give this output

```
10.0000   40.0000
0.1000    0.3000
6.0000    3.0000
2.0000    2.0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_data(:,my_index)
```

but I'm suspicious that this is so simple that it doesn't satisfy your (background) requirements ...

Comment: Oh my god!. It's embarrassing. I had a mistake in something else but I thought that I had a mistake on this. Thx for your answer anyway.